# tail/head piping remove newlines

Tags: bash, shell-script, tail, head

If have the following file /tmp/f1.txt file coming from the stdout redirection of the result of a PostgreSQL bash script execution :

```
 id  
-----
 517
 518
 519
 520
 521
 522
(6 rows)

INSERT 0 6
```

I wish I could iterate over those ids to perform other actions.

For now, I am able to retrieve the desired ids as follows (i'll always get 5 values ) :

```
cat /tmp/f1.txt | tail -n +3 | head -n5 -
```

This returns :

```
517
518
519
520
521
```

Which is exactly what I want.

So, the next step would be to read every single line. So in my case I'd store the result in a variable, and then read line by line :

```
LINES_UPDATED_CNT=$(cat /tmp/f1.txt | tail -n +3 | head -n${LINES} -)
echo -e $LINES_UPDATED_CNT
```

My issue here is that this command yields the following result :

```
517 518 519 520 521 522
```

The newlines are lost, can't understand why.
What would be the optimal way to do this, without wirting the cat/tail/head result into another file and reading it in a while ?

Thank you !

Comment: Looked at the link, and found out that eval function is to be used. The link looks like to hold *many* interesting and useful information, although understanding is not easy. I was able to finally get into a solution. Shall I provide the final solution or do you prefer to submit it afshin ?

Comment: there's no reason to `eval`, it's the unquoted expansion in the `echo` that makes your newlines disappear. But you don't need the variable either, just direct the first pipeline to a `while read` via pipe or process substitution